# Digital signature not listed in VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba, certificate, digital-signature

I have a digital signature that appears in File => Info => Protect Workbook => Add a digital Signature
[image]
However, it does not appear in VBA Editor list: Tools => Digital Signatures => Choose. In VBA it only list my self-created digital signature.
[image]

How do I add the real digital signature to my VBA project?
I enabled all purpose for the real one. It's visible on Personal tab in Internet options and is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate needs to be a certificate that was issued for code signing. Certificates that were issued for other purposes will not appear there. So check the purpose of your certificate.

Therefore you can run `certmgr.msc` (using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) find your certificate, right click on it -› properties and check which purposes are set in the first tab there. If it does not mention code signing there, you cannot use that certificate.